shopify graphql queries for users and staff members
I have a shopify plus and the read_users permisisons. Via graphql I'm able to retrieve a bunch of data from my  staff member like name and such.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to fetch the user role the  staff member is assigned to. Another problem I have is that I'm not able to query the staff member list, every field  I try, I get an error saying that "query" is not recognized. So my questions are:

how can I get the user role of the staff member or, at least, the list of the user roles created in the admin?
how can I query/filter the staff member list (other than first, last, etc)?

